# integrate head in a one-liner bash CLI

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I have this command

```
$ sha1sum file.bin | cut -f1 -d " "
```

that computes the sha1sum of some eeprom content. The pipe followed by cut is to get rid of the file location in the output and retrieve only the sha1.

My issue is that I need to compute the sha1 over the first `N` lines of the `file.bin`. The file is a table/array of lines of 32 bytes (fixed lengths).

I know I have to put in some `head -n N`, but don't know how with the redirections. The syntax is `head -n N <file>`.

I tried naively `sha1sum file.bin | cut -f1 -d " " | head -n 8` but it doesn't work. I need the shell to understand somehow this: `sha1sum(head -n 8 file.bin) | cut -f1 -d " "`, but we can't use mathematical function syntax in shell I guess...

How to do it please? Regards

Comment: Are you sure you can use `head` with binary content? I'm not.. You may want to refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155085/fetching-individual-bytes-from-a-binary-file-into-a-variable-with-bash to see how you can extract bytes out of the binary file

Comment: Good point @YoavKlein. I assumed it was a readable file (like the [Intel HEX file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)) but the .bin extension is suspect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the output of `head` the input of `sha1sum`, just as the output of `sha1sum` is the input to `cut`.

```
head -n 8 file.bin | sha1sum | cut -d " " -f1
```

or, if the file is binary, use the first N bytes with `-c`

```
head -c 1024 file.bin | sha1sum | cut -d " " -f1
```